# Let a Form stay on top even if ToggleDesktop() (shell32.dll) is called

Tags: vb.net, desktop, shell32

is there anyway to capture and cancel or do something like me.activate when the show desktop event is triggered and make my form visible?

note:
The show desktop event is triggered by another app which is installed in some of my users pc. I am not trying to make my form always on top of other open windows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe we need more Information about 'show desktop event'. I don't get the point

Comment: to be precise, my app is getting hidden when another app is launched in some of my users computers. After doing some research i found out that the other app is triggering "Show Desktop event" programmatically something like when you press win+D or win+m keys or click on "show desktop" icon in win xp.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, you mean to let your form stay on TopMost even if `ToggleDesktop()` in `shell32.dll` is executed.

By far I can say: there is none. They tried to experiment at [codeguru](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?416271-Immunize-form-against-quot-Show-Desktop-quot-%28toggledesktop%28%29-desktop.scf%29) but it seems there were no successfully results.

Comment: yes i meant topmost (on desktop and not on other applications). I tried Dim ProgmanHwnd As IntPtr = FindWindowA("Progman", "Program Manager")
        Dim a = SetParent(Me.Handle, ProgmanHwnd) which i got from some other forums and worked fine in development environment (Win 7) but dint work on my users XP pc (my guess is that they are using same SetParent for their app also).